# Django runserver problem "python manage.ph runserver"

Tags: python, django

i have a django file, and i'm trying to see that file in django but when i command "python manage.ph runserver" it's not showing anything. just emty line in cmd after i commend. i tried to fin and error in my pip but there wasn't any problem. and the file is fine as well. i tried to create and run another file from scrach but it didn't work too.  so is there anyone who knows the solution ?[as you can see, when i try to run the file in django, it's not responding anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0GHj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. use `python manage.py runserver`.